# Comment maker in python 3

Tags: forms, python-3.x, comments

I' d like to make a simple script that create comments in this page:
http://pountex.altervista.org/risolvere-bug-apt-get/

I tried with requests:

```
import requests

url = "http://pountex.altervista.org/wp-comments-post.php"

payload = { "comment":"a",
            "author":"a a",
            "email":"a@a.com",
            "url":"a.com",
            "submit":"Commento all'articolo",
            "comment_post_ID":"178",
            "comment_parent":"0",
            }

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

And by making a http request:

```
import socket

url = "http://pountex.altervista.org/wp-comments-post.php"

request = open("request.txt").read()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("pountex.altervista.org", 80))
s.send (str.encode(request))
```

you can find request.txt here: http://pastebin.com/iWYRk7rk

Any advice to comment that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help.

I solved by making this script:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser()
url = "http://pountex.altervista.org/risolvere-bug-apt-get/"
browser.open(url)
form = browser.get_form(id="commentform")
form["comment"] = "a"
form["author"] = "a a"
form["email"] = "a@a.com"
form["url"] = "a.com"
browser.submit_form(form)
```